# Want to restrict users from accessing Storage account - Create an RBAC role to deny Access to Storage Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-activedirectory

We have a few storage accounts in the subscription and wants to restrict access to only a few users and an application. 
so other than the Subscription owners and a backup application "ComVault" which has an App ID no one should have access to these Storage Accounts. Initially all the users have been provided access at the subscription level and the access to the storage accounts are by default inherited. We have tried the following:

1. Created an AD Group and Added all the users and Application to which we did not wanted to access the storage account and then we applied the following Custom Role to the same :

{

"Name": "Custom - Microsoft.Storage.DenyAccess",

"Id": "",

"IsCustom": true,

"Description": "Deny permissions to Commvault Storage Accounts v20190409.",

"Actions": [

"*"

],

"NotActions": [

"Microsoft.Storage/*/Read",

"Microsoft.Storage/*/Write",

"Microsoft.Storage/*/Delete"

],

"NotDataActions": [

"Microsoft.Storage/*/Read",

"Microsoft.Storage/*/Write",

"Microsoft.Storage/*/Delete"

],

"AssignableScopes": [

"/subscriptions/"

]

}

Logically this should work but it doesn't. Kindly suggest what we can do to achieve the above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to assign access at the top level (subscription) but block access to specific resources. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do that using access control (IAM) and it sucks.

Regardless, I think you're already in the right track but I think it also depends on what the users in that group CAN access. For instance, here's a sample one I did a few months ago where all users in the group can READ everything (ALL resources) in Azure, EXCEPT a few resource types*.

```
{
    "Name":  "Limited_Reader",
    "IsCustom":  true,
    "Description":  "Gives you READ-ONLY access to everything, except a few resource types.",
    "Actions":  [
                    "*/read"
                ],
    "NotActions": [
                    "Microsoft.Storage/*",
                    "Microsoft.KeyVault/*",
                    "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/*"
                   ],
    "DataActions":  [

                    ],
    "NotDataActions":  [

                       ],
    "AssignableScopes":  [
                             "/subs/*****
                         ]
}
```

So that gives them READ ONLY access to everything in Azure but they can't do anything to the aforementioned resource types. In your case if they need write access to everything else, just find the proper permissions (I think its what you already have - */write and */delete).

Side Note: Microsoft's official solution to this problem seems to be something called Azure Blueprints which they just release a couple weeks ago and I don't have any knowledge about that tool.